# CoffeeScript function returning a function and not a value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript, google-chrome-devtools, firebase

I have a hash that calls a function to get a value. The problem is, the function is returning the function inside rather than the values it should.

(user is defined above this hash)

My hash:

```
userInfo = {
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email,
        cars: getCars(user.id),
      }
```

Which calls this function:

```
  getCars = (userId) ->
    id = parseInt(userId)
    userRef = new Firebase("https://demo-firebase.firebaseIO.com/users/#{id}/")
    userRef.on('value', (snapshot) ->
      if snapshot.val() == null
        ["toyota"]
      else
        snapshot.val().cars # returns an array of cars
    )
```

When I'm in the debugger and stepping through the function, it returns on the `userRef.on` line rather than the correct place in the `if/else` statement.

Here's the compiled JS:

```
getCars = function(userId) {
  var id, userRef;

  id = parseInt(userId);
  userRef = new Firebase("https://demo-firebase.firebaseIO.com/users/" + id + "/");
  return userRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
      return ["toyota"];
    } else {
      return snapshot.val().cars;
    }
  });
};
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: You really should specify the radix when calling [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): `id = parseInt(userId, 10)`.

Comment: @muistooshort Modern browsers don't treat leading zeros as octals any more. Since the target platform is known to be OK (Chrome Extension implies Chrome  /Opera 15+), it's safe to drop the radix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the data you are getting from firebase is event-driven and asynchronous, so you can't just return it as if this was synchronous code. You need to use a either a callback, a promise, or event handler.

```
getCars = (userId, callback) ->
  id = parseInt(userId)
  userRef = new Firebase("https://demo-firebase.firebaseIO.com/users/#{id}/")
  userRef.on 'value', (snapshot) ->
    if snapshot.val() == null
      callback ["toyota"]
    else
      callback snapshot.val().cars # returns an array of cars

userInfo = 
  id: user.id
  email: user.email
getCars user.id, (cars) ->
  userInfo.cars = cars
  #Don't user userInfo until here as it's not ready/populated yet!
```

(Note the node convention is `callback(errorOrNull, value)`, but I'm omitting error handling here for simplicity)

Also note that almost everyone new to async javascript makes this mistake, but it's not a simple syntax gotcha, it's a fundamental thing you at some point (maybe today) you will have the aha/lightbulb moment. The thing to do is step through this in the chrome debugger and note the **order each line of code executes** in relationship to **time**. The line with the `if` statement executes LATER IN TIME after `getCars` has already returned. And note if you step through it it will skip right over the body of the `'value'` event handler because that line just DEFINES the event handler, but it doesn't actually EXECUTE it until the data arrives, so if you want to debug in that, you need to set a breakpoint on the first line of that function (where the `if` statement is).

There are 3 common paradigms available for this: event binding, promises, and callbacks. All will work. It would be a good exercise for you to code this same functionality with each paradigm and understand that they all basically give you a way to wait for some data to arrive and then run some code in response to the data arriving.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Going to mess around with this. I'll post any follow-up questions in a bit

Comment: I understand that the `if` statement executes later in time. Also, this isn't a Node app, if that matters. I'm not quite clear on your syntax when calling `getCars` in the third-to-last line with your use of `user.id, (cars) ->`. That seems strange to me

Comment: So that means call the `getCars` function passing 2 arguments - `user.id` as argument 1 and a function (the callback) as argument 2. The callback is an anonymous function defined right there.

Comment: Ah, I was just confused by the syntax. I usually write things as `getCars(userId, cars)` but I guess in this instance it would be `getCars(userId, (cars) -> userInfo.cars = cars)`, right?

Comment: Exactly. I omit the parens around the function arguments because doing so makes it easy to pass a function as the last argument and not have a closing paren way further down the file.